# How to stub a method returning void with ref arguments with Rhino

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, stubbing

I can't find a way to stub methods with ref arguments if they return void, as in the following example:

```
public interface Interface1 {
    void Method1(ref int i);
}

public class Class1 {
    static public void Main() {
    MockRepository mockRepository = new MockRepository();
    Interface1 interface1 = mockRepository.Stub<Interface1>();
    int i = 1;
    //SetupResult.For(interface1.Method1(ref i)).OutRef(1);  Can't compile
    interface1.Method1(ref i);
    LastCall.Repeat.Any();
    mockRepository.ReplayAll();
    int j = 0;
    interface1.Method1(ref j);
    if(j == 1) Console.WriteLine("OK");
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Thanks,
Stenio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rhino Mocks 3.5 has a new interface for constraints, replacing .OutRef() and others.  See the [documentation](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx#OutandRefarguments):

```
Interface1 interface1 = MockRepository.GenerateStub<Interface1>();
int i = 1;
interface1.Stub(x => x.Method1(ref Arg<int>.Ref(Is.Anything(), i).Dummy);
int j = 0;
interface1.Method1(ref j);
if (j == 1) Console.WriteLine("OK");
```

Comment: Anyway it's quite a lot of syntactic sugar for a method that returns something in its ref/out arguments. I wonder if a declarative approach would have been better, wouldn't it?

Comment: I probably wouldn't have changed it, but it's not my library. :)